# Questions about finding general work?

Tags: discussion

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/323/how-can-a-westerner-land-an-it-job-in-a-third-world-country

I am thinking questions like this should be not constructive.  It is really broad and unlikely to develop answers that will help anyone else.

My problem is I do not think that what the questioner is asking is necessarily off topic.  It could probably be broken into several on topic questions.

I fear that opening it up to these questions will end up with too many, *How do i get a job at company X?* questions.

Comment: Questions about finding work, yes. General questions (about *anything*) no.

Answer (score 5):

I mostly agree. These questions strike me as very similar to "What should I study next?" questions on Programmers.SE. The rationale is that we know almost nothing about the asker, and are therefore unlikely to be helpful to either the asker or to future visitors.

Some other examples which may appear are

- How do I get a job at company X?
- Which companies have X, Y and Z benefits?
- What are the best companies to work at in industry X?
- What are some tips from switching from industry X to industry Y?
- How can I get a job in country X?

On the other hand, I agree with you that your example question has some good potential questions in it. I suspect there will be a fine line here that moderators will need to make judgement on.

Comment: Don't wait for moderators. They'll be looking at you for guidance... If you think there's something worth salvaging in that question, point it out and / or just edit the question to emphasize it. Otherwise, vote to close it.

Comment: Keep in mind too that moderators are actually at a disadvantage in that they don't have close votes. It's much easier as a moderator to make a decision to close a question when he/she sees community support in the form of close votes from other community members. This moderation has to come from the community, even once the diamond moderators are appointed.

Comment: The community needs to decide the line, here on meta. Moderators only enforce.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about specific aspects of job-hunting (like [What is the purpose of references?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/440/what-is-the-purpose-of-references) , [If you've lost contact with a person, should you stop listing them as a reference?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/266/if-youve-lost-contact-with-a-person-should-you-stop-listing-them-as-a-referenc) , [How do I maintain a good relationship with an employer after resigning?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-do-i-maintain-a-good-relationship-with-an-employer-after-resigning)) I think are OK.  These are just a few I grabbed, there are a bunch of other good ones already.

Questions like "how do I get a job?" or the categories root45 listed are too broad (and many too ephemeral - IBM's interview in 1980 and their interview today are probably radically different), and I agree they should be considered not constructive or plain off-topic.

---

In short: I agree with Benjol's comment - broad questions like this are bad. Good, pointed questions are probably OK.