# "Job marketplace" vs. "workplace"

Tags: discussion, faq-content, on-topic-definition

[How can a westerner land an IT job in a third world country?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/323/how-can-a-westerner-land-an-it-job-in-a-third-world-country) appears well on its way to closure.  Some reasons for closing this specific question appear in [this meta question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/questions-about-finding-general-work).  However, I wish to address one specific comment on the [actual question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/323/how-can-a-westerner-land-an-it-job-in-a-third-world-country):

> I also think that this isn't about the workplace, it's about finding jobs (or to say it another way, the job "marketplace"), which is off-topic in my opinion.

I disagree with this *particular* reason for closure as off-topic.  The job search, hiring practices, and the like seem like good questions for this site so long as the questions are otherwise good.  Another way to look at this is that career-oriented questions that otherwise meet the guidelines for good questions should be welcome here (I think).

What say you?  Agree?  Disagree?  Should we include something about the job search process specifically in our list of what is on topic?  Are there certain job-search- or career-related questions that we specifically do *not* want?

Comment: Agreed, the job market is a huge part of what the site is about so far (hiring-process is our biggest tag...). That question wasn't a great fit but not because of this.

Answer (score 4):

This question went off topic with *Im looking for almost an IT "peace corps" type role. How could I find listings like this?*  Had the question been about the process of getting a visa, or some other specific process related to getting a job overseas it would have been on topic.

This question quickly became **point me to the new monster.com**.  That is why it is off topic.

The same standards for questions still apply as they do for all SE Sites.  If we allow the site to go off the rails by allowing bad questions we might get closed for being a low quality site.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** Also, see this related question: [Can I ask "Professional Careers and Advice" questions here?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/can-i-ask-professional-careers-and-advice-questions-here)

I'll use my answer to elaborate on my comment - it's possible that I'm already gaining a reputation for being the "off-topic" police, and in a few cases it's been pointed out that perhaps I am being too narrow in my interpretation. :P

My comment comes from a broader question regarding what the topic of the site is itself. I interpret it to be about the workplace, the place where people are performing work, and can include questions on structure, organization, politics, advice on the dynamics of work, etc.

## The argument for allowing these questions, as I understand it

It's on topic because, though it's not about the performance of work, it's about finding work, which is hard to separate from doing work.

## The argument against allowing these questions, from my perspective

This question in particular asks where to find a particular kind of work. To me, it sounds like a question that can be answered by a google search, and it's hard for me to imagine valid answers that are more than one line. The best answers I can imagine for this answer essentially turn it into a poll.

### Am I going too narrow here?

As the scope, tone, and culture of the site is formed, I find these sorts of questions especially interesting, and I'll concede that I side more with "make it highly focused" and "let's see what happens", in a general sense. Maybe that's good, maybe it's not.

Comment: It may be too early to try to narrow the scope. There were many people who were excited about this site starting because there isn't a suitable place anywhere on the network to ask general career questions.

Comment: 'Hard cases make bad law', I don't necessarily follow you all the way from 'this is a bad question' to 'getting a job questions are out of scope'. That would put *everything* related to getting a job out of scope (interviews, cvs, etc.). As jmort says, that may be going a bit too far (especially if it means yet another SE site...)

Comment: Can "getting a job" questions be properly handled when tagged as such?