# Job Search/Transition and Workplace Policy and Procedure Only? Confusing Scope

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I have asked a question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43533/what-are-my-options-for-not-using-my-personal-cards-when-not-provided-with-a-com) and told it was not relating company policies and thus is not appropriate for the forum.

> If you were asking how to convince your employer to change their policies, that would be more of a Workplace question.

Per the "[What Questions can I ask Here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)", company policies and procedures are not specifically listed though either. There are also several question about [working remotely](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/what-can-i-do-to-prepare-for-working-remotely), [traveling for work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11681/how-to-inquire-and-ask-for-traveling-allowance-and-benefits-for-going-out-of-the), and other such topics.

The list does specifically cover working conditions though which is what my question is about.

Vaguely related, I also attempted to seed a "Remote Employees" community in Area 51, and was told it was a duplicate of this one and was in the scope of this one which based on some of the voting activity is not clear that is the case.

Most of the questions here seem to be about obtaining ([job market](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/job-marketplace-vs-workplace)) or exiting employment and anything beyond that seems to at first glance seems to get down voted.  Also being my question is being voted as 'off-topic' but this regarding [overly verbose text messages from a student](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43526/too-much-verbosity-in-text-messages) *(not even an employee)* one is considered 'on-topic' per the description in the link above makes no sense.

So what is the actual scope of this community if the Help says one thing, questions say another, and close / down vote activity implies another?

Comment: I deleted my question out of frustration as defined scope and community action do not align and everyone seemed hell bent on saying it was a travel question or a personal finance question or some other question even though it was specific to the work place.

Comment: Consider asking your question at http://money.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

> So what is the actual scope of this community?

From the "on-topic" link in the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **The Workplace Stack Exchange** is a Q&A site about the workplace and other career-related topics. With your help we're working to build
>   a library to every question about the workplace related to:
>
> - Finding employment (resumes/cv/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)
> - Maintaining employment (promotions, pay increases, harassment, bullying, poor working conditions, communication problems, etc.)
> - Leadership in the workplace (motivating people, encouraging people, making decisions, holding hard conversations, intervening in
>     unproductive situations,  asking for and giving help, etc.)
> - Terminating employment (notice period, breaking the news, handing over work, reference letters, relieving letters, etc.)

It is not clear to me how your question falls into any of those four categories.

Your question basically boils down to:

> How can I spend money abroad using a credit card (or alternate form of payment)  which minimizes risk of the payment method being compromised?

This question has nothing to do with the scope above and is far more relevant to sites directly addressing payment and travel (such as either Travel or Personal Finance). It is solely about the technology used for payment. Perhaps this was not your intent, but it is how the question is written.

If your question was more like any of the following, it would be a Workplace issue rather than career/travel:

- How can I approach my boss regarding inconveniences of absorbing personal liability for all travel expenses when travelling for work?
- What options do I have for business expenses on international travel when my boss refuses to allow corporate credit cards?
- How can I convince my company/boss/manager/HR to allow corporate credit cards for international travel?

These all focus on the actionable Workplace related aspects to your situation and what is actionable in that context.

Comment: I still disagree. My question is as specific to the workplace, as for personal finance nor personal travel do not get a per-firm advance nor have to create expense reports. All of your suggested questions imply a narrow & specific solution of ultimately issuing a company credit card. Not providing ideas for alternatives nor a solution for a lone employee in a large corporation to ultimately solve the root issue.

Comment: @CRSouser I can see how you'd be convinced it's a workplace issue -- after all, it's travel for work. The question itself though isn't about anything related to the workplace, it's about what options exist for people who want to use a card overseas and avoid skimming. If your question was about how to approach your boss about covering the additional costs/fees of a prepaid card, then it would be more relevant to the workplace, but as is I think enderland's answer is spot on.